# How to use WCF Service between 2 projects in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, wcf

I am trying to build a tool that sends data to another tool via some mediator between the 2 tools.

Suggestions are welcome to use something else, however for those that know how to use the WCF, can you walk me through how it is done ?

I watched some videos online, but they seem to use the web. Both applications are used on the desktop, and both are windows forms application tools.

Here is where I am at.
 I created a toolX, and toolY. Both different projects. Here is what I want.
 I want to use toolX to start toolY, and send it data. toolY will receive the data, start processing it. Once finish, I need toolY to trigger that it is finished go back to toolX so it can process other data to toolY.

I created a WCF service, but I am not sure what to do with it, where to implement my code so it starts toolY and send it the data. I did not include anycode because it is pointless since it is an empty service class with [Service Contract] section, and [Data Contract] Section.
Any help, examples, tutorials, websites are much appreciated

Comment: Are the two applications running on the same computer? Or is this a remote link?

Comment: @ John Wu, yes indeed, both are running on the same computer.